# Blocks of text side by side in footer

Tags: html, footer

I am trying to achieve something like this..

http://line25.com/ see in the footer where he has "About Line25" then "Most popular posts" with block of text by side of each other?

I do this in my footer and on smaller screen resolutions it moves all over the place.

http://akaleez.co.uk/Templates/1/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason it "moves all over the place" is that you specify `width: 100%` for your footer. When the width of the viewport is smaller than the width of the three text blocks, one of them will display below the other two.

Add another wrapper around your blocks of text like this:

```
<div id="foot">
  <div id="footer-wrapper">
    <div class="box1">...</div>
    <div class="box2">...</div>
    <div class="box3">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then add the following to your CSS definition:

```
#footer-wrapper {
  min-width: 990px;
  margin-left: 180px;
}
```

Then remove the `margin-left` from `.box1`.

Note that this will force your whole page to be 1170px wide and display a scroll bar at the bottom of the window if there is not enough space to display it all.
If don't want that, try and add this to your CSS:

```
#foot {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Great it is working. Just one other thing is when it is in smaller resolution the content in the index text moves over where as the footer stays stuck and cuts of one of the box of text when in a smaller resolution.

Comment: Try to change the CSS to `#footer-wrapper { width: 990px;
margin: 0 auto; }`, similar to your `container` `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the boxes in a wrapper div and center it like this:

```
.wrapper {
margin:0 auto;
display:table;
}
```

Display table will cause it to be exactly as wide as the 3 boxes. Next remove the margin of the first box.

Currently it has 180px margin, which obviously will not center propperly if the screen is smaller or wider then expected.